# keytool error java.io.filenotfoundexception (access is denied)

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, windows-10, android-keystore

I am using Windows 10 Home, I did run the cmd as administrator and still getting the error "Certificate was added to keystore keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore (Access is denied)"

Command I have used is :

"C:\WINDOWS\system32> "C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\keytool.exe" -importcert -file "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\upload_cert.der" -keystore "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore"

[image]
Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Run the command from your home directory and specify the full path to the keystore binary. `PS> cd $HOME;
PS> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\keytool.exe -keystore clientkeystore -genkey -alias client` .

Comment: tried to run the script but got the error the term "C:\Program is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet". 
PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\keytool.exe.

When i add the script with double quatation "" like below i got the error "Unexpected token '-importcert' in expression or statement"

PS C:\Users\Administrator>  "C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\keytool.exe" -importcert -file "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\upload_cert.der" -keystore "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore"

Comment: I fixed by just replacing the Jks file with keystore